# Keep IIS express running when VS2019 debugging stop

Tags: visual-studio-2019, iis-express

How to keep IIS live after stopping VS2019 Debug mode?

I tried with Tools-> Debugging -> "unchecked" Enable Edit and Continue, and this approach doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get this working properly by changing these settings:

**Tools > Debugging > Edit and Continue should be off**

**Right click the Project in solution explorer > Properties > Debug > Hosting Model: Out Of Process**

As for the consequences of switching to Out Of Process, I don't think there are any as it's only for debugging.

Comment: Disable it in the properties of the project (.NET Framework classic): `Properties -> Web -> Debuggers -> Enable Edit and Continue`

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit of a late response, but just in case here it goes:

The best way to be able to exit Debug mode and leave iisexpress running is to start your application without the debugger in the first place, `<ctrl + F5>` and then attach the Debugger `<ctrl + alt + p>` to the iisexpress process, you'll see it on the list. Once you're done debugging just stop the debugger and that's it, you can always reattach it later if needed, `<shift + alt + p>` will reattach so you don't have to select the process again.

The downside to doing this is that you won't be able to debug startup part.

Hope this helps